# List of folders where security group grants access to (Windows server 2003)

Tags: windows, security

My question is very simple and I think many people are trying to find out answer so please try to help.

In Active Directory, when administrating server, you can create or list security groups but the server can be very huge so finding out where security group grants access to manually is almost life time task.

Is there any program or, what I definitely prefer, script (batch, PS, ..) someone uses for this specific task?

Thank all of you in advance, answers will be very appreciated.

PS: I've heard it's possible to do it using Hyena. I am using this tool but I never saw this list to be provided. If anyone uses Hyena for this, please let me know how instructions how you do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an expert, Mark Russinovich, who created an excellent set of tools, called SysInternals. So Microsoft bought him, and now his great tools are available at their website for free. One of them is [AccessChk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922), see if it fits your needs.